# Is it possible for a specific member in a queue to not be notified?

Tags: queue

Is it possible for a specific member in a queue to not be notified? We are dealing with a request in which a user mentions if it is possible that he could not be notified for assigned cases in their queue but he is in the queue.

I've checked the email settings and queue settings but I could not find anywhere to support this request.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-stop-email-notification-to-Queue-members-1327108336049&type=1)?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes I checked this link but in this link it says that this would send to all Queue members. What I need to do is to stop sending a notification to a specific member in the Queue.

Comment: If you have a queue email defined and send email to members unchecked, that’s the only way at least I know of.